# Create Progress Bar for task in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to export Registry to to reg file in Powershell so that, I use command:

```
REGEDIT /E C:\backup.reg
```

But when it running, it doesn't show any status for me to know how much percent it complete.

So which way can I use to show percentage of complete of this task in screen to monitor?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Regedit is a compiled application and it returns what the developer chose to return (see `regedit /?` for options).

You would have to recreate it yourself as a Powershell function or find someone who's done it already.